# How to transparently run a script before docker entrypoint?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, docker, aws-cloudformation, docker-entrypoint

I'm automating deployment of java app in a docker container in cloudformation templates. I need to setup an env variable for java crash logs but I need to keep the path unique per container. I can't modify docker image or dockerfile.

To do so I'm using $HOSTNAME from docker container which is unique enough. The problem is I can't use it as usual docker environment variable, because it's set after the container is launched. The way around it is to alter the entrypoint with setting the env variable and launching the original entrypoint after that.

```
EntryPoint: 
            - /bin/sh
            - -c
            - export JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -XX:HeapDumpPath=/mnt/crashdumps/java_$HOSTNAME.hprof" 
&& ./entrypoint.sh
```

(it's a cloudformation YAML template for AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition but same thing can be expressed in docker cli)

It worked fine until java container provider changed the placement of entrypoint shell script. Now the **shell injection** looks really dirty in the code, because I need check if the file exists and requires more maintenance (i.e. in case entrypoint path or filename will be changed again).

Is there a better way to either:

1. dynamically setup a path with a container name using different method than modification entrypoint; or
2. inject just an "export" command and run the original entrypoint whatever the name and path is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a dynamically generated path for your java crash logs, I would suggest to dynamically generate unique name in the docker entrypoint script itself.

Like this one, which I tested and works fine.

```
#!/bin/sh

# Create some random file in /tmp
filename=$(head /dev/urandom | tr -dc A-Za-z0-9 | head -c 13 ; echo '')
touch /tmp/$filename
cat /tmp/$filename
export filename=$filename
```

Each time I run this script, which will happen once you spawn such multiple containers. It will generate files in `/tmp` with random names.

```
$ ls /tmp/
DzJXInMvJAgvN  f0rgIMIt115h7  sSgVDXj2zvRTh  x4dBEciezQnix
```

So in this case entrypoint will generate a unique name during each invocation, so there will be no any need to invoke anything prior to `docker entrypoint`.

Hope this helps.

**Update**

So far I understand that you want to override filepath of java crash logs, without editing dockerfile or the entrypoint script. The `-XX:HeapDumpPath` option of `JAVA_OPTS` if I'm right.

You can try this

```
$ docker run -itd --env JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -XX:HeapDumpPath=/mnt/crashdumps/java_$(head /dev/urandom | tr -dc A-Za-z0-9 | head -c 13 ; echo '').hprof" alpine sh
$ docker exec -it 75f062ff8906 env
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
HOSTNAME=75f062ff8906
TERM=xterm
JAVA_OPTS= -XX:HeapDumpPath=/mnt/crashdumps/java_MyRZcSKxFtZaF.hprof
HOME=/root
```

As you can see `JAVA_OPTS` is overridden with appropriate filename.
Hope this helps, let me know.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The problem is I can't modify the dockerfile or the entrypoint script as at the deployment stage it's not visible. I only download the image and run it. If only there would be a clever way to add this code into the existing entrypoint shell script that would work.

Comment: Ohh I see. Let me check that.

Comment: But you can still uodate the `-XX:HeapDumpPath` option ins your `docker run` command, am I right? If so then can you provide me your `docker run` command.

Comment: it was not possible to just add 'run' command as the cluster is being setup from cloudformation TaskDefinition template.  We solved this finally with ensuring the docker container is starting an app with exec, what resolved the variable. Thanks for your advices, they helped us better understand the issue!